# Xamarin SKEncodedImageFormat Jpeg background added

Tags: xamarin, uwp, background, skiasharp, image-conversion

I'm coding in Xamarin with SkiaSharp libraries for UWP (eventuallay Android but not ios) with VS 2019

With this code

```
SKBitmap signature = SKBitmap.Decode(canvasImg.Encode());
using (var image = SKImage.FromBitmap(signature))
using (var data = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg, 80))
{
    // Save data to a stream
    using (var streamSign = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.Path + "\\work\\Models", "signature.jpg")))
    {
        data.SaveTo(streamSign);
    }
}
```

I get a **jpg** file of my canvas. This is working perfectly. The issue is the image format defined with this line:

```
SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg
```

I need jpg format (and absolutely not png). The issue is this converter add me a black background and the black draws are invisible.

Anyone know how can i set the background added white ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible workarounds

1. Convert the image to `Png` type and add a transparent background on it .

   Refer to [Adding transparency to a SKBitmap image results in black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497469/adding-transparency-to-a-skbitmap-image-results-in-black-background) .
2. Since there is no option of `Jpg` for `SKEncodedImageFormat` ,  we could use external tools(like paint , photoshop) to transfer the image to `Png` or `Jpeg` type .

   Refer to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b466c566-6666-4cc9-9cdc-88d8c0032e2b/adding-transparency-to-a-skbitmap-image-results-in-black-background?forum=xamarinlibraries