# Adding transparency to a SKBitmap image without looking at all pixels

Tags: c#, skiasharp

I found this case here, [Adding transparency to a SKBitmap image results in black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497469/adding-transparency-to-a-skbitmap-image-results-in-black-background)

I want to ask a further question about that, Is there any faster way to do this without looking up each pixel?

I mean for this part;

```
for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
```

It is working for me, I even changed this a bit. That change is about changing the specified color to the transparent one. However, performance is not good because of looking at all pixels.

System.Drawing.Bitmap.MakeTransparent can do this speedy way but it works only on the windows platform. This is my problem. Because of that, I need to change it with the SkiSharp.

Comment: It's possible to do image operations a LOT faster if you use "unsafe code" (effectively writing raw byte data directly to memory) https://davidthomasbernal.com/blog/2008/03/13/c-image-processing-performance-unsafe-vs-safe-code-part-i but that comes with its own issues/restrictions

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Basic . Even though that is a good explanation it is not a good fit for me. Because I need to handle this by using the SkiaSharp. Because System.Drawing support only Windows platform. As such, I continue to investigate an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution;

```
var transparencyColor = SKColors.White;

var pixels = skBitmap.Pixels;

var transparent = SKColors.Transparent;

for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
{
      if (pixels[i].Red == transparencyColor.Red && pixels[i].Green == transparencyColor.Green && pixels[i].Blue == transparencyColor.Blue)
      {
           pixels[i]=transparent;
      }
 }

 skBitmap.Pixels = pixels;
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>